# SBT and External Libraries in Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am starting a Scala project and I'm using SBT and Intellij 13 as my IDE.

I have the following build.sbt file, but I can't seem to get the dependencies in the SBT "libraryDependencies" section to show up in "External Libraries" after running "sbt update".

The following is my build.sbt:

```
name := "myapp-scala"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.3"

resolvers += "spray repo" at "http://repo.spray.io"

resolvers += "spray nightlies" at "http://nightlies.spray.io"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka"  %% "akka-actor"       % "2.2.0",
  "com.typesafe.akka"  %% "akka-slf4j"       % "2.2.0",
  "ch.qos.logback"      % "logback-classic"  % "1.0.13",
  "io.spray"            % "spray-can"        % "1.2-20130712",
  "io.spray"            % "spray-routing"    % "1.2-20130712",
  "io.spray"           %% "spray-json"       % "1.2.3",
  "org.specs2"         %% "specs2"           % "1.14"         % "test",
  "io.spray"            % "spray-testkit"    % "1.2-20130712" % "test",
  "com.typesafe.akka"  %% "akka-testkit"     % "2.2.0"        % "test",
  "com.novocode"        % "junit-interface"  % "0.7"          % "test->default",
  "org.scalautils" % "scalautils_2.10" % "2.0",
  "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "2.0" % "test"
)

scalacOptions ++= Seq(
  "-unchecked",
  "-deprecation",
  "-Xlint",
  "-Ywarn-dead-code",
  "-language:_",
  "-target:jvm-1.7",
  "-encoding", "UTF-8"
)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

[image]

Comment: What versions of scala plugin and IDEA (13..what?) do you have?

Comment: Scala Plugin version 0.26.361
InteilliJ version 13.0.1

Comment: I just had the same issue with IDEA 13.1.1 and refreshing SBT projects did it for me (View -> Tool Window -> SBT -> Refresh all SBT projects)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best way to start working with IDEA 13 and a `sbt` project is this:

- Make sure that you have the `sbt` plugin installed

[image]
[image]
[image]

- If you have it installed, then simply start a sbt project:

[image]
[image]

This should fix everything up for you, and you can run your commands via the sbt console:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To integrate Sbt with Intellij IDEA you need to use this plugin:
https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea

It provides you with the Sbt task `gen-idea` which will generate the files required to configure IDEA with your project.

Comment: No you don't. [In newer IDEA versions integration should work out of the box](http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2013/11/18/built-in-sbt-support-in-intellij-idea-13/) without any sbt-to-idea conversions.

Comment: Running the gen-idea task after adding the IDEA plugin did work.  I have read similar comments to wwhat om-nom-nom mentioned.  At least in my case I did need to install the plugin and run that sbt task.

Comment: I just put the build.sbt into a directory and used the "Import Project" option in IDEA, and I chose the build.sbt, and it seemed to take care of the rest for me...

Comment: Yes, but this should not be necessary in Idea 13.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on IntelliJ CE 14.0.2
The project/app name under build.sbt and project/build.scala file need to be same. That helped fixing the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what @samspired said
 
I just made the **sbt.Project** variable name exactly like the name of the project module name and it solved the problem.
 go to **File -> Project Structure -> Modules** 
 and see what the module name is - (it doesn't have to be like the project directory name but if you didn't change it, it's probably it )

```
// this file is in the path of "../Somewhere_in_file_system/MyProjectName/build.sbt"
lazy val MyProjectName /*this is the module name*/ = (project in file("."))
      .settings(
        scalaVersion := "2.11.8",
        name := "com-company-blabla-myproject" //..... and all the other sbt properties
    )
```